# Successful login fails in symfony

Tags: symfony

I have a login form. If i try to login the login is never redirect me to the target page. What i'm doing wrong or it is because of the server configuration (Module rewrite already enabled)?

I will show some files:

**security.yml**

```
security:
    access_decision_manager:
        strategy: unanimous
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        secured_area:
            anonymous: ~
            pattern:   ^/
            form_login:
                check_path: login_check
                login_path: login
                default_target_path: homepage
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:
                path:   logout
                target: login
            switch_user: {role: ROLE_ADMIN}

    providers:
        administrators:
            entity: { class: AppUserBundle:User, property: username }

    encoders:
        App\UserBundle\Entity\User: 
            algorithm: bcrypt
```

**routing.yml**

```
homepage:
    path:  /
    defaults: { _controller: AppUserBundle:User:profile, id: null }

login_check:
    path: /login_check
    methods: POST

logout:
    path: /logout
    methods: [POST, GET]

login:
    path:     /login
    defaults: { _controller: AppUserBundle:Login:index}
```

**LoginController**

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $utils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        return $this->render('AppUserBundle:Login:index.html.twig',
            [
                'last_username' => $utils->getLastUsername(),
                'error' => $utils->getLastAuthenticationError() ? 1 : 0
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

**Template file:**

```
<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post" role="form" class="form-signin">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'msg.username'|trans({}, "messages") }}" type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'msg.password'|trans({}, "messages") }}" type="password" id="password" name="_password" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}" />
                        <button name="submitbutton" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">{{ 'msg.login'|trans({}, "messages") }}</button>
                    </form>
```

**Environment:**

- ubuntu 14.04 64
- php 5.5.28-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
- mariaDB 5.5
- symfony 2.6.7

How can i solve my issue?

**I solve my issue:**

To solve my issue i add this line into my config. yml.

```
framwork:
    session:
        handler_id: ~
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
form_login:
    always_use_default_target_path: true
```

Comment: unfortunately, the problem still exists. I noticed that the session files in app/cache/dev/sessions/ was generated but all session files have 0KB.